# signature and argument passing in a custom scoring function in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am working on a custom scoring function.It needs to get extra data rather than the usual X,y prescribed in all the scikit-learn APIs.
Unfortunately, I need to call it by GenericUnivariateSelect within a pipeline, so it will be called by the internals of GenericUnivariateSelect with signature (X, Y). How to pass extra arguments?
For now, I solved as follows, but requires a horrible inline function definition. How to solve this?

```
Z= #... exists in the scope

def myScore(X,Y):
    return aScoringFunction(X,Y,ExtraData=Z)

reliability_filter=GenericUnivariateSelect(myScore,mode='MinScore',param=0.9)   
reliability_filter._selection_modes.update({'MinScore': SelectMinScore})
```

where SelectMinScore is a trivial extension of BaseFilter builtin

```
class SelectMinScore(BaseFilter):
    # Sklearn documentation: modes for selectors : {‘percentile’, ‘k_best’, ‘fpr’, ‘fdr’, ‘fwe’} I have added minscore
    # custom selector: 
    # select features according to the k highest scores.
```

Comment: As in your last questions, this is not currently possible. You need to extend the inbuilt classes to handle this yourself.

Comment: what if the underlying classes are changed in a later version?I am worried

Comment: If they change, you need to change your code. If you dont want to change your code, then freeze the environment (use a virtual environment, with fixed versions of all libraries).